# Edge doesnt allow permission prompt for notifications

Tags: javascript, push-notification, microsoft-edge

I have added push notifications to a customer page using the Notifications API. The notifications generally work in all major browsers as well. However, Edge blocks all permission requests by default (see ticket https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/webpush-notifications-blocked/a65a0e3e-dd0f-427f-b16e-31a98d60b0c4). I have also checked out and tested several existing projects (also using the push API and service-workern), none of them give me the usual permission prompt in Edge. In all common browsers I get the permission prompt, as long as no notifications for the website have been allowed/denied yet. Does anyone have an idea how I can force Edge to show the prompt or is it just a matter of waiting for an Edge update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push Notifications Request for edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669454/push-notifications-request-for-edge)